# Hydrogen Package Atom Editor — Weird Display

Tags: python, atom-editor

recently I installed the Hydrogen package in the atom editor. 
As my scripts do require user input and often an output based on the input as well, I would like to have a nice view on the output while being able to give input at the same time.

Right now, the input line is perfectly visible, however the output is blurred in the background of the editor. I put a picture down below, so you can see what I see. (Input line: obviously visible. And response hardly visible on the right...) [This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ywj.png)

Does anyone know a fix?

[
I'd be fine with seeing the output in the atom-internal terminal as well, if I could enter the input in there too, in case hydrogen cannot be changed in such a way.
]

Answer (score 0):

You must have the Hydrogen package installed. Go to the package menu item and under this menu you should see an entry for Hydrogen. Clicking on this Hydrogen entry opens a menu as shown below.

[image]

Clicking on "Run Cell" or "Run All" will execute your code and print output on screen at bottom of editor window. If you have an input statement you get a solid colored screen waiting for input. I often use an input statement like this:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

and when I run this I first get the screen below waiting for user input.

[image]

Then after entering your data in the box and hitting return you'll get the editor screen back with Hydrogen output as shown below.

[image]